# Java classes not interacting properly

Tags: java, class, classpath

I have two Java class files: *primegen* and *primecheck* sitting in the same directory. *primegen* calls a public static function from *primecheck*. *primecheck* compiles fine.

However, I receive the following compilation error in *primegen*:

```
primegen.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable primecheck
location: class primegen
          } while (!primecheck.prime(primeCandidate));
                ^
```

Shouldn't Java be checking other (compiled) classes within the same directory? Does Java have a problem with *primecheck* being in lower-case letters (e.g. Is it treating *primecheck* as a variable instead of a class?)?

**Update with Complete Code**

Code for primegen:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class primegen
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            int numBits = Integer.parseInt(args[0].trim());
            System.out.println(generatePrime(numBits));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("You must enter a positive integer number of bits.");
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger generatePrime(int numBits) throws Exception
    {
        if (numBits < 1)
            throw new Exception("You must enter a positive integer number of bits.");

        BigInteger primeCandidate;
        Random rand = new Random();

        do
        {
            primeCandidate = new BigInteger(numBits, rand);
        } while (!primecheck.prime(primeCandidate));

        return primeCandidate;
    }

}
```

Code for primecheck:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class primecheck
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            BigInteger primeCandidate = new BigInteger(args[0].trim());
            if (prime(primeCandidate))
                System.out.println("True");
            else
                System.out.println("False");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("You must enter a positive integer.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean prime(BigInteger n) throws Exception
    {
        if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == -1)
            throw new Exception("You must enter a positive integer.");
        else if (n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || n.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
            return false;

        int maxIterations = 1000;
        BigInteger a;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
        {
            a = randomBase(n);
            a = a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n);

            if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static BigInteger randomBase(BigInteger n)
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        BigInteger a;

        do
        {
            a = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), rand);
        } while ( !(BigInteger.ONE.compareTo(a) <= 0 && a.compareTo(n) < 0) );

        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you can update your question with the minimum amount of both classes' (but syntactically valid) code, my guess is folks will be able to see the problem fairly quickly. When in doubt (or even if not), post code! :-)

Comment: I am afraid that by omitting the function definitions you are actually omitting the code where the problem is :-). See my updated answer below. There's nothing wrong with the names of the functions.

Comment: I'll add the code for prime() and generatePrime().

Comment: No it doesn't have a problem with lower-case. Making the class name Capitalized is just a convention - though one you should follow.

Comment: I notice that javac's error output does not exactly match the source code you posted (in your source code, the line starts with a closing brace; in javac's output, it doesn't). By editing the code before posting, you can actually be hiding the problem. Can you verify that you actually get an error when compiling the code as posted? As you can see in my answer, the same code seems to compile fine.

Comment: The complete code has been posted.

Comment: Alright, I'm flummoxed now. The complete code compiles without a problem. What compiler are you using btw?

Comment: I have good news and bad news. The good news is that your code compiles fine. The bad news is that I don't have a clue how we can help you further.

Comment: I do believe this is the exact reason why classes should start with upper case and variables with lower case

Comment: Agreed with Vineet. You might be using the old version of javac.

Comment: I tried compiling on a different computer, and it worked. Thanks for all of your help everyone, even though we couldn't find the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not care about names being all lowercase or uppercase. These are just naming conventions (Java **is** case sensitive, but will not enforce any particular naming convention).

**Edit:** (after a few iterations :)

The code you posted compiles fine. The problem is obviously somewhere else (javac command line arguments, classpath...)

Comment: Typically the compiler will report something like "unable to invoke non-static method from a static context" if that's the case.

Comment: Can you post a self-contained example? It's difficult to guess without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2):

Check your classpath — does it have "." in it? If not, no, Java will not look in the current directory for classes.

No, Java doesn't care about the class names being in all lower case (provided they're ***consistently*** lower case, both where used and where defined), **but** the convention is for classes to have a capital first character (and usually to be camelCase), e.g. `PrimeGen` and `PrimeCheck` vs. `primegen` and `primecheck`. It doesn't relate to your problem, but it will tend to startle and confuse people looking at the code (like people on SO). :-)

**Update** Are these classes in a package? If so, you need to be sure that they're in the right place relative to the class path as relates to the package. But typically that would have shown up on your `import` statement, as opposed to your use of `primecheck`...

Comment: My CLASSPATH is ".;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip", so that must not be the problem, but thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: I'm using lowercase letters only because it is required by the spec :)

Comment: These classes aren't in a "package" -- just in the same directory with no "fancy" import statements, only basic ones.

Comment: @DT3: *"I'm using lowercase letters only because it is required by the spec"* What spec? Certainly no Java spec I'm aware of, it's in direct contravention of Sun's coding guidelines.

Comment: @DT3: So, basically take everything that teacher tells you with a grain of salt, then. If they're ignorant of the conventions of the language, heaven only knows what else they're ignorant of. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Java *is* case sensitive.  Perhaps your class is defined as `PrimeCheck` or something similar?

Comment: No, it is declared as "primecheck."

Comment: @DT3: Well then you'll have to post more information than you have so far.  The scenario as you're reporting it doesn't seem likely, sorry.

Comment: It is so unlikely that no one seems to have an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a compilation error, rather than a runtime one, it is important to understand that the compiler cannot find the `primecheck` class when compiling `primegen`. The current directory (by inference, the current package) is included by default, by the javac compiler in the user classpath, whenever any symbols have to be resolved during compilation. However, if this is overridden by the CLASSPATH environment variable, then symbol resolution will fail.

*There is also a likelihood (I haven't verified this) that the '.' symbol in the classpath environment variable is not expanded into the current working directory, and hence it would be better to explicitly specify the location of the .class files.*

Therefore, it is important to specify the location of the primecheck class when compiling primegen, either by the `-classpath` option (to indicate where the .class files can be found) or the `-sourcepath` option (to indicate where the compiler can find the source code of the class).

**Reference**:

1. [The javac tech notes.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)
2. [Setting the classpath for javac](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: *"There is also a likelihood (I haven't verified this) that the '.' symbol in the classpath environment variable is not expanded into the current working directory,"* Yes, it is. I use this all the time.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I wasn't disputing whether it works at all. I was hinting at the possibility of a bug in the specific version of the JDK that OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a symbol conflict in your `primegen` class.

Declaring another variable `primecheck` within the same scope results in confusing the compiler on how it should be treating the reference - is the code referencing the class or the object? It ends up treating it as an object reference, and since the object's class does not have the method `prime()` defined in it, it throws up the error. Of course, the example also vindicates why naming conventions are a good idea.

Consider the following snippets of code, and the resulting error when compiling `primegen`.

**Class primegen**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class primegen
{
    public static void main(String args[]){}
    private static BigInteger generatePrime(int numBits) throws Exception
    {
        if (numBits < 1)
            throw new Exception("You must enter a positive integer number of bits.");

        BigInteger primeCandidate;
        Random rand = new Random();
        String primecheck = "";
        do
        {
            primeCandidate = new BigInteger(numBits, rand);
        } while (!primecheck.prime(primeCandidate));

        return primeCandidate;
    }
}
```

**Class primecheck**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class primecheck
{
    public static void main(String args[]){}
    private static BigInteger randomBase(BigInteger n){return null;}
    public static boolean prime(BigInteger n) throws Exception
    {
        if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == -1)
            throw new Exception("You must enter a positive integer.");
        else if (n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || n.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
            return false;

        int maxIterations = 1000;
        BigInteger a;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
        {
            a = randomBase(n);
            a = a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n);

            if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The resulting error is:

```
primegen.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method prime(java.math.BigInteger)
location: class java.lang.String
        } while (!primecheck.prime(primeCandidate));
                            ^
1 error
```

Comment: This is the first (uhm.. second :) thing I thought about, but does not seem to be the problem after he posted the complete source code..

Comment: @Grodriguez, yeah I noticed that as well. But the similarity of the message with the original wants me to leave this behind, just in case it helps. For some reason, the compiler appears to be failing to resolve primecheck , going by the error message that he's posted.

Comment: "Declaring another variable primecheck within the same scope..."  I think you may be confusing "primecheck" and "primeCandidate."